# Get PIXEL VALUES of a circle located?

Tags: python, opencv, region

I have parameters of circle on a image: radius and coordinates of center. Is it possible to return the location of pixels along a circle? I need to get the all pixel values along the circle line.
I tried get coordinates by next solution:

```
...
cx = int(img.shape[1]/2)
cy = int(img.shape[0]/2)
radius = 700
angle = np.linspace(0,  2 * np.pi, 360)
X = (np.round(cx + radius * np.cos(angle))).astype(int)
Y = (np.round(cy + radius * np.sin(angle))).astype(int)
...
```

But if angle is not agreed with radius I miss neighboring pixsels:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a continuous circle as the outline of the domain X² + Y² ≤ R². If you observe the symmetries, you will notice that the circle can be decomposed in 8 arcs. Consider the arc from (R, 0) to the intersection with Y=X (octant 2 in the picture): it is made of displacements from (X, Y) to (X, Y+1) or (X-1, Y+1) only. If we plug this in the disk equation, we need X² + (Y + 1)² ≤ R² or (X - 1)² + (Y + 1)² ≤ R², and we give priority to the first inequality if it can be satisfied (the second is automatically satisfied).

```
X, Y:= R, 0
while X > Y:
    # 8 symmetries
    Plot(X, Y);  Plot(Y, X);  Plot(-X, Y);  Plot(-Y, X); 
    Plot(X, -Y); Plot(Y, -X); Plot(-X, -Y); Plot(-Y, -X); 

    if X² + (Y + 1)² > R²:
      X-= 1
    Y+= 1
```

[image]

Comment: The above will result in holes for certain radii, for example 50 (and above?). After the while loop an additional check is required: if x  == y than you need to call plots for the current value of x and y.

Answer (score -1):

You can never get all the points on a circle, as the points are continuous. What you can do is to get more points on the circle, so that the drawing looks continuous.

Change the number of samples to generate here from 360 to something greater, for example 720.

```
angle = np.linspace(0,  2 * np.pi, 720)
```

You can keep increasing until you're satisfied with the result.

However, as you are drawing with openCV and the points all have to be integers, you will more than likely still have gaps. That's why the best solution is to use openCV's drawing function

```
cv.circle(img,(x_cen,y_cen), radius, colour, thickness)
```

Comment: This trial-and-error approach is not satisfactory as it is not automatic. And the circle function draws the circle but does not give the coordinates.

Comment: Oh yes he needs the coordinates I forgot

Comment: @YvesDaoust No, `circle` does not directly give the coordinates, but `numpy.where()` will after the circle is drawn.

Comment: @beaker: if you mean detecting the white pixels in the image, this is pretty inefficient. And if the goal is to fetch the existing pixel values rather than just getting the coordinates, you need an auxiliary image. Also note that the points will come in raster order rather than following the curve. I would not recommend this method.

Comment: Yes it is inefficient, but for reasonably-sized images, it’s quick enough and simple to implement.